# Remove Duplicate custom objects from NSMutable Array making sure to keep newest duplicate object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsset

I have an `NSMutableArray` of custom objects. Each contains an ID string that is unique, and each contains an `downloadedDate` property.

Objects could get added twice so I need to check the ID for duplicates, and if I find a duplicate I need to keep the one that has the newest date.

Currently I am doing the following to remove duplicates, but it doesn't take into account keeping the object with the newest date.

```
NSArray *originalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableItems];
NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableSet *names = [NSMutableSet set];
for (ZSSObject *g in originalArray) {
    NSString *destinationName = g.code;
    if (![names containsObject:destinationName]) {
        [uniqueArray addObject:g];
        [names addObject:destinationName];
    }
}
NSArray *uniqueObjects = uniqueArray;
```

Objects get created like this:

```
ZSSObject *obj = [ZSSObject alloc] init];
obj.code = @"12345";
obj.downloadedDate = [NSDate date];
```

**Is there an easier way to do that I want than having a bunch of copies of my array and nested loops?**

Comment: It sounds like you should use a dictionary rather than an array. Then you can check the date before you add the new object to the dictionary.

Comment: Sorting originalArray before the loop according to descending date will solve your problem i guess.

Comment: @Paulw11 - I just posted an answer, let me know if this is what you were thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion to use an `NSDictionary` instead, I came up with this solution:

```
NSMutableDictionary *objDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (ZSSObject *g in mutableItems) {

    ZSSObject *addedObj = objDict[g.code];

    if (addedObj) {

        // Compare dates
        if ([addedObj respondsToSelector:@selector(dateDownloaded)]) {

            if ([g.dateDownloaded compare:addedObj.dateDownloaded] == NSOrderedDescending) {

                [objDict setObject:g forKey:g.code];

            }

        }

    } else {
        [objDict setObject:g forKey:g.code];
    }
}

NSArray *uniqueObj = objDict.allValues;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I would do